# NoReverseMatch with generic DeleteView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I cannot figure out why I'm getting `NoReverseMatch` when trying to use this view. I'd like to get generic views to work because it seems like alot less code to do the same task.

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, UpdateView, CreateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import *

class ProductDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Product
    success_url = reverse_lazy('homepage_view')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None,
                         unique=True, populate_from='name')

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('product_delete_view', args=(self.slug,))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**urls.py**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    path('product/delete/<slug:slug>/', views.ProductDeleteView.as_view(), name='product_delete_view'),
]
```

**template**

```
<p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{product.get_delete_url}}">Delete Product</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Where is your 'homepage_view' declared?

Comment: @bertinhogago In my views.py. I also have it names 'homepage_view' in my urls.py

Answer (score 1):

you should add the app name also in get delete url method

```
 def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('main:product_delete_view', args=(self.slug,))
```

Comment: It's in my post